# Redirect on admin Save

Tags: django, django-admin

How can I redirect a user to different app on Save?

I have two app, say `app1` and `app2`. If a user clicks on Save in `app2` then it should be redirected to `app1` rather then the default page.

I don't want to do a  customform.

Comment: Why no accepted answers for any questions?

Comment: On save where? In the admin, in a custom form, where?

Comment: in admin not in custom form.it is simple admin, i am overriding the  save function

Answer (score -9, accepted):

def change_view(self, request, object_id,extra_context=None):

```
result = super(mymodeladmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, extra_context)

result['Location'] = "your location"

return result
```

Comment: This is not a great answer: what happens if the change_view is unsuccessful? Also assigning to result['Location'] is not very django-like (even if it may work).  The answer above (by Daniel Roseman) is a good one.

Comment: You should validate Roseman's answer to get 2 points of reputation :) You can learn how to use stackexchange [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: @Glide -- what's validating (is it distinct from upvoting, which I did do). Your docs link to was a bit broad.

Comment: @Glide still not following what you mean by "validating" (or maybe I misinterpreted your comment - perhaps you were talking to the OP, not me...)

Comment: Good question, bad answer.

Answer (score 105):

To change the redirect destination after save in the admin, you need to override `response_add()` (for adding new instances) and `response_change()` (for changing existing ones) in the `ModelAdmin` class.

See the original code in `django.contrib.admin.options`.

Quick examples to make it clearer how to do this (would be within a ModelAdmin class):

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue=None):
    """
    This makes the response after adding go to another 
    app's changelist for some model
    """
    return HttpResponseRedirect(
        reverse("admin:otherappname_modelname_changelist")
    )


def response_change(self, request, obj, post_url_continue=None):
    """
    This makes the response go to the newly created
    model's change page without using reverse
    """
    return HttpResponseRedirect("../%s" % obj.id)
```

Comment: i havent said that i am not accepting the answer.It was typing mistake and i have corrected it.

Comment: can u explain it little more .I am not able to find it out

Comment: What does a typing error have to do with it? You have asked 35 questions on StackOverflow, and you haven't accepted a best answer for a single one. That is very bad manners.

Comment: i am not aware of this that we have to accept answer manually.

Comment: Daniel's answer helped me - I'd just mention that a user might also want to take into account '_addanother', i.e. check that neither '_continue' nor '_addanother' are in request.POST before choosing to redirect back out of admin to one's app.

Comment: @ha22109 You should see a grey checkmark to the left of each answer, underneath the rank up/down arrows (The checkmark only appears on answers to questions you have asked).  To accept an answer, you click the checkmark and it turns green.  This helps other folks who have the same question know which answer to look at first. 
Edit: Hmm, I see now that you have accepted an answer below.  I wrote this in response to your reply to Daniel's comment above thinking you hadn't accepted any answer. I'll leave it anyway just in case.

Answer (score 44):

To add to @DanielRoseman's answer, and you DON'T want the user redirected when they choose **Save and continue** and not the Save button, then you could use this solution instead.

```
def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue="../%s/"):
    if '_continue' not in request.POST:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(get_other_app_url())
    else:
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).response_add(request, obj, post_url_continue)

def response_change(self, request, obj):
    if '_continue' not in request.POST:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(get_other_app_url())
    else:
        return super(MyAdmin, self).response_change(request, obj)
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me out.

Comment: @dan-mantyla this works lovely for me but do you happen to know how to stop the redirect on save and add another?  Thanks

Comment: @Davies-Barnard its been a long time since I've worked with Django. Maybe this could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14126371/in-django-how-to-override-the-save-and-continue-feature/14126372

Comment: Thanks @DanMantyla.  Its actually a lot simplier but I couldn't see wood for the trees.  The name of the Save and Continue button is _continue and likewise the name of the Save and Add Another button is _addanother I just needed to adapt the code above to distinguish between these values.

Comment: Django Admin also supports  `_saveasnew` save button (displayed if `save_as=True` is added to your `ModelAdmin ` class), so you should also handle it just as you handle `_continue`.

Answer (score 2):

Given the previous answers I would suggest to override `response_post_save_add` and `response_post_save_change` methods. So you don't skip django's default logic in `response_add` and `response_change`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at URL namespaces... You could probably use HttpResponseRedirect + reverse to redirect the user inside of your overridden save method. Keep in mind that this is a new feature in Django 1.1 and is not supported in 1.0.x.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces