# Django - Admin : Editing child model without inlineForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, parent-child

Standard example:

```
class Author(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
  #... Many other fields ...
```

I'd like to edit the `Book`s from the `Author` change page.
I tried with [InlineModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) but since `Book` has many fields, it's not easy to edit.
That's why I tried to put links towards the *children* on the author/change template.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="{% url admin:content_scribpart_add %}">Add a Book</a></li>
{% for book in original.book_set.all %}
  <li><a href="{% url admin:myapp_book_change book.id %}">Edit {{ book }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But there are several questions

- How can I prepopulate the related `Author` id in the `Book` form
- How can I make the *Save* button to go back to the related `Author`
- Am I on right track ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, sure.

1. Append `author` primary key as `GET` parameter to your url:

   ```
   <ul>
     <li><a href="{% url admin:content_scribpart_add %}?author={{ object_id }}">Add a Book</a></li>
   {% for book in original.book_set.all %}
     <li><a href="{% url admin:myapp_book_change book.id %}?author={{ object_id }}">Edit {{ book }}</a></li>
   {% endfor %}
   </ul>
   ```
2. Modify the corresponding `ModealAdmin` for book, override [`response_add()` and `response_change()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339845/redirect-on-save/1356549#1356549). Note that we also [override `formfield_for_forein_key`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey) in order to pre-populate `author` field:

   ```
   from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
   from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

   class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

       def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
           if db_field.name == "author":                    
               try:
                   author_pk = int(request.GET.get('author', ''),) 
               except ValueError:           
                   pass
               else:
                   kwargs["initial"] = Author.objects.get(pk=author_pk)

           return super(BookAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)

       def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue=None):
           return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin:myapp_author_change', args=(obj.author.pk,))
           )

       def response_change(self, request, obj, post_url_continue=None):
           return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin:myapp_author_change', args=(obj.author.pk,))
           )
   ```

Comment: `Author.objects.filter(pk=author_pk)` filters the select box but doesn't pre populate

Comment: Finally I'm going to use `kwargs["initial"] = Author.objects.get(pk=author_pk)` instead of `kwargs["queryset"] = Author.objects.filter(pk=author_pk)`

Comment: It's also `admin:myapp_author_change` instead of `admin_myapp_author_change`