# Modify django admin form "save and add another" function

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

In my admin forms I have some default submit actions e.g. "save", "save and continue", "save and add another". I want to modify the last one adding some prepopulated fields, so the form will open with some fields filled according to the previous object. Is there a way to do so?

## UPD

Found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14068598/8386351

Comment: Dear do you want to redesign and edit admin panel which is built in?

Comment: @MuhammedBilal Yes, admin users of the site will create a lot of records with similar values in some fk-fields, so I want to make it a bit easier for them. I mean, there are four different fk in the model, but two of them has a big probability to have the same value as in the previous created record, so I could let admin to use some shortcut like 'save and create another with the same value of fields 1 and 2'

Comment: Go in my computer disk where you installed python go inside python search for LIB go inside LIB folder then search site-packages enter this folder then enter in django folder

Comment: there you can access all built in forms templates etc

Comment: Thanks but I'd looked for a more concrete answer. Found it now.

Comment: Yeah this is not complete but you got the idea ,