# In Django, how to override the 'Save and continue' feature?

Tags: django, django-admin

I need to add some pre- and post-save logic to my ModelAdmin, but only when the user submitted the form via the 'Save and continue editing' button and not the 'Save' button. How can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just like overriding the normal save method, you need to override the `save_model()` function in your ModelAdmin, which includes the request `object`. From the `request` object you can get the `POST` object, which will include a `'_continue'` key **if the user clicked the 'Save and continue button'**. Example:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, changed):
        if '_continue' in request.POST:
            # add your code here
        return super(ServerAdmin, self).change_view(request, obj, form, changed)
```